# Latex does not display in titles and comments

Tags: support, mathjax, ios-app, android-app

With MSE accessed by mobile app, latex symbols appear as they are. Is there a way to make them appear in full font ? Comments cannot be edited/deleted. Text does not zoom in by drawing fingers apart on display. May be I miss some obvious option. However no problem with the main question and answer.

Comment: You can zoom on browser on mobile, at least on my version of chrome + android.

Comment: I think that either ([meta-tag:ios-app]) or ([meta-tag:android-app]) tag should be added to this question - depending on which app the question is about.

Comment: You seem to be asking about several limitations of the mobile app.  To display $\LaTeX $ in Comments, select the Comment by touching, then use the dropdown menu at upper right  on the screen.  One of the options there is to display MathJax.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks, this helped.

Comment: Note also that once you select (by touching) one of your own Comments, the top of the screen will show a trash can icon (in addition to the drop down menu already pointed out), and this allows you to delete your Comments.  There are some bugs in the mobile app, e.g. I was unable to post this Comment from the mobile app (had to use the desktop/browser interface)

Comment: Yes it did, also accepted Matt Samuel's answer.