# In the StackExchange iPhone app, how do I get MathJax to work in comments in the Math StackExchange section?

Tags: support, feature-request, bug, mathjax, comment

I’m not sure this is the right place to ask but it seemed like it is.

I don’t get this problem for other sections of StackExchange. Just the “Mathematics” section.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Searching a bit both here and on [meta.se] using some combinations of the tags (ios-app), (mathjax) and (comments) I found: [Viewing LaTeX in comments on the iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302397) and [Latex does not display in titles and comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26982). (I do not use the app myself, so I can't really check whether the suggestions provided there actually work.)

Comment: It's the same on Math Overflow (and probably on all sites with MathJax enabled). As explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302400/196432) you can request a LaTeX rendering for a comment.

Comment: I see. Why isn’t it set up to render automatically? Why do you have to request it?

Comment: @AdamRubinson: I have no idea. But since this is an issue with the iOS app (on multiple Stack Exchange networks) it is better asked on https://meta.stackexchange.com. Just note that [the app development is currently frozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/ios-app/info), so I wouldn't be too optimistic about a change in the near future (or at all).

Comment: Not sure whether this is the same on the iOS app, but on Android you can highlight the comment by tapping on it, press an icon (three vertical dots, representing "more options") on the top right of the screen, and then choose "Render MathJax".